# Error in relevel.default(delays.df$ORIGIN, ref = "IAD") : 'relevel' only for (unordered) factors

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Trying to work on this code in my book (which keeps giving me code that doesn't work)

```
#### Table 10.6

delays.df <- read.csv("/Users/CHAPTER 10 ASSIGNMENT 6/FlightDelays.csv")
head(delays.df)

# transform variables and create bins

delays.df$DAY_WEEK <- factor(delays.df$DAY_WEEK, levels = c(1:7),
                             labels = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"))
delays.df$CRS_DEP_TIME <- factor(round(delays.df$CRS_DEP_TIME/100))

head(delays.df)

DAY_WEEK     CRS_DEP_TIME
<fctr>        <fctr>


# create reference categories

delays.df$ORIGIN <- relevel(delays.df$ORIGIN, ref = "IAD")
delays.df$DEST <- relevel(delays.df$DEST, ref = "LGA")
delays.df$CARRIER <- relevel(delays.df$CARRIER, ref = "US")
delays.df$DAY_WEEK <- relevel(delays.df$DAY_WEEK, ref = "Wed")
delays.df$isDelay <- 1 * (delays.df$Flight.Status == "delayed")

# create training and validation sets
selected.var <- c(10, 1, 8, 4, 2, 9, 14)
train.index <- sample(c(1:dim(delays.df)[1]), dim(delays.df)[1]*0.6)  
train.df <- delays.df[train.index, selected.var]
valid.df <- delays.df[-train.index, selected.var]

# run logistic model, and show coefficients and odds
lm.fit <- glm(isDelay ~ ., data = train.df, family = "binomial")
data.frame(summary(lm.fit)$coefficients, odds = exp(coef(lm.fit))) 

round(data.frame(summary(lm.fit)$coefficients, odds = exp(coef(lm.fit))), 5)
```

****I can't get past any of the relevel commands because of the following error:****

```
delays.df$ORIGIN <- relevel(delays.df$ORIGIN, ref = "IAD")
```

> Error in relevel.default(delays.df$ORIGIN, ref = "IAD") :
> 'relevel' only for (unordered) factors

What I am understanding is that my variables are factors and the relevel command does not work on my factors. I don't understand how to fix it? If this isn't the case, I really don't understand how to fix it.

As always, any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Well, for `delays.df$DAY_WEEK` you specify levels (i.e. `levels = c(1:7)`), so you shouldn't need to 'relevel' it. Perhaps try commenting out the line `delays.df$DAY_WEEK <- relevel(delays.df$DAY_WEEK, ref = "Wed")` or alternatively removing `levels = c(1:7)` from the original command ?

Comment: From your `head` call, `delays.df$ORIGIN` does not exist. So you may be trying to `relevel` on `NULL`.

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez - thank you

Comment: There's a bunch of unreproducible stuff going on here. The first line uses `read.csv()` to read the file, which should result in an ordinary base-R data frame, not a tibble. The second `head()` call prints out the data types (e.g. `<fctr>`), which implies that the object is now a tibble.  I think we're not being shown the full/reproducible workflow here.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to R 4.0, the option `stringsAsFactors` was `TRUE` by default, i.e. string-like variables would automatically get converted to factors when being read in by (e.g.) `read.csv()`.  This is no longer the case unless you set `options(stringsAsFactors=TRUE)` before reading in your data (or specifying that option as an argument in your `read.csv()` call, i.e. `read.csv("[filename]", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)`.)

You could set the option in one of those ways, or you could explicitly convert to factor before you `relevel()`:

```r
delays.df$ORIGIN <- relevel(factor(delays.df$ORIGIN), ref = "IAD")
```

Judicious use of `transform()` (base R) or `mutate()` (tidyverse) could make your setup code a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank you! I will ad this to my coding practice.

Comment: if this answer solved your problem, you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...